# What may be the cause of the following error on python OPC UA server with SCADA client?

Tags: python, opc-ua, wincc

Here is the code for setting up OPC UA Server:

```
import sys
from opcua import ua, Server

server = Server()

server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:4808/")

server.set_server_name("ServerOPC")

uri = "http://server"
idx = server.register_namespace(uri)

objects = server.get_objects_node()

Object_1 =objects.add_object(idx,'MyFirstObject')
Object_2 =objects.add_object(idx,'MySecondObject')
Object_3 =objects.add_object(idx,'MyThirdObject')

Discret_1 = Object_1.add_variable(idx,'Discret_1',[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],varianttype=ua.VariantType.Int16)  
Discret_2 = Object_2.add_variable(idx,'Discret_2',[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],varianttype=ua.VariantType.Int16)  
Analog_3  = Object_3.add_variable(idx,'Analog_3',[10,20,30,40,50],varianttype=ua.VariantType.Int16)    

Discret_1.set_writable()
Discret_2.set_writable()
Analog_3.set_writable()

server.allow_remote_admin(allow=True)
server.start()
```

I can succesfully read and write the variables with UaExpert. But i have it failed with SCADA-client (WinCC). I have connection established and can browse the nodes (variables). The types are compatible. But when I start runtime mode my server gives the following error.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found out that problem was not about the SCADA-client or the server, but about virtual machine. I don't know what exactly it was, but on another VM everything is going well.